# Email signature blocks are displaying weirdly, broken up and with padding

Tags: html, gmail, html-email

I made a html email signature, opened it up in browser where it looks fine, and pasted it into my gmail signature section, and each individual block has now got padding in between, and some of the blocks are side by side instead of next to each other. 
Strangely by some fluke I managed to get it to look fine on outlook.This is what it's supposed to look like this https://postimg.org/image/uytldx3zd/

Here is the code i'm using- what am I doing wrong? 
Any fix would be much appreciated,
Thanks

```html
<html>
     <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
     td {line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em; }
     img { display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; }
    </style>
    </head>
    
    
    <!-- Paste Code Under This Line
    _________________________________________________________________________________ -->
    
    <title>emailsignature_500flat</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <!-- Save for Web Slices (emailsignature_500flat.psd) -->
    <table id="Table_01" width="550" height="357" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
      <td>
       <a href= callto:4411893280328><img src="https://s20.postimg.org/tk69dnist/emailsignature_500flat_01.jpg" width="254" height="50" alt=""><a href= callto:441189328032></td>
      <td rowspan="3">
       <a href=http://thereadinesscomp.com><img src="https://s20.postimg.org/o8rcsyrl9/emailsignature_500flat_02.jpg" width="296" height="113" alt=""><a href=http://thereadinesscom.com></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <a href=http://thereadinesscomp.com><img src="https://s20.postimg.org/s54ooxx59/emailsignature_500flat_03.jpg" width="254" height="32" alt=""></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <a href=https://www.linkedin.com/company/129626/><img src="https://s20.postimg.org/oya55b4zh/emailsignature_500flat_04.jpg" width="254" height="31" alt=""></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
       <a href=mailto:info@thereadinesscomp.com><img src="https://s20.postimg.org/c6vyytq2l/emailsignature_500flat_05.png" width="550" height="146" alt=""><a href=mailto:info@thereadinesscomp.com></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
       <img src="https://s20.postimg.org/t7ev7hnod/emailsignature_500flat_06.jpg" width="550" height="98" alt=""></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
    </body>
    <!-- Keep Pasted Code Above This Line!
    _________________________________________________________________________________ -->
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following errors in your code.

- missing closing anchor tags,
- missing colspan
- CSS should be inline always

Here is the HTML you need:

```html
<table id="Table_01" width="550" height="357" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td style="line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em;">
        
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td style="line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em;">
      
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em;">
       <a href= callto:4411893280328><img src="https://s20.postimg.org/tk69dnist/emailsignature_500flat_01.jpg" width="254" height="50" alt="" style="display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; "></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td style="line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em;">
       <a href=http://thereadinesscompany.com><img src="https://s20.postimg.org/s54ooxx59/emailsignature_500flat_03.jpg" width="254" height="32" alt="" style="display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; "></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td style="line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em;">
       <a href=https://www.linkedin.com/company/1296265><img src="https://s20.postimg.org/oya55b4zh/emailsignature_500flat_04.jpg" width="254" height="31" alt="" style="display: block; float: left; padding: 0; " /></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
      
      
      </td>
      <td style="line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em;">
     <a href=http://thereadinesscompany.com><img src="https://s20.postimg.org/o8rcsyrl9/emailsignature_500flat_02.jpg" width="296" height="113" alt="" style="display: block;" border="0"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  

        </td>
  
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em;">
   <a href=mailto:info@thereadinesscompany.com><img src="https://s20.postimg.org/c6vyytq2l/emailsignature_500flat_05.png" width="550" height="146" alt="" style="display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; "></a>
  </td>
  
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em;">
   <img src="https://s20.postimg.org/t7ev7hnod/emailsignature_500flat_06.jpg" width="550" height="98" alt="" style="display: block; float: left; padding: 0;">
  </td>
  
 </tr>
  
  
    </table>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried your code but unfortunately, it is still broken up when I add it to gmail! And also when I add it to outlook too, here is a screenshot of what it looks like https://s20.postimg.org/t8q6mvjp9/Screen_Shot_2018-03-20_at_17.03.46.png

Comment: It's because of the row and colspan you have used. I will update my code today and you can take it from there.

Comment: If this worked for you please choose it as the correct answer.

Comment: It is still shown as broken up when I upload it on outlook , did you update the code? I cannot tell!

Comment: Ok i have rewritten the whole code for you now. This time it should work.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working!! I will mark as correct answer, really appreciate your help, thanks :)

Comment: @Atko, i rejected your edit and some how this question is no longer the accepted one?

Comment: It is no longer the accepted one because it didn't resolve the issue on further inspection.